# Error while Sigining Plugin for Dynamics CRM 2016 using Visual Studio 2015 Professional

Tags: visual-studio-2015, dynamics-crm-2011, dynamics-crm-2016

> Hi All,
>
> I am trying to sign my assembly **(Plugin for Dynamics CRM 2016)** using
>   **Visual Studion 2015 Professional**. But it gives me the following error.

[image]

> Could't find any help till now.
>       Thanks in advance

Comment: Run as admin otherwise it can't save the output

Answer (score 1):

try the following:

1. I don't know if it's Window 7 or the company policy, but take ownership of the `C:\Users\All Users\Application Data\Microsoft\Crypto\RSA\MachineKeys` folder and give yourself full control.
2. try running Visual Studio as Administrator.

[Strong name access denied error on Windows 7 64-bit from Visual Studio and sn.exe](http://www.nathanfox.net/blog/38/Strong-name-access-denied-error-on-Windows-7-64bit-from-Visual-Studio-and-snexe)

[Generating SampleKey.snk File - Access Denied](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/4b5b10a8-0db5-4ba4-b5f3-b90741589854/generating-samplekeysnk-file-access-denied?forum=clr)